# Vue3 / typescript: how to type component props for 2d array

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I am converting an existing vue project (written in JS) to Typescript. I am mostly getting on well, but am having a problem with passing an array as props to a component.
I am using Composition API / SFC.

For one component (which doesn't need an array), I have this structure:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  import type { TrackTile } from '../../env.d';

  interface Props {
    tile: TrackTile,
    item: number
  }
  const props = defineProps<Props>()
  console.log('keyItem script setup');
  console.log(props.tile);

</script>
```

This transpiles without errors and then runs fine, so I assume my basic syntax is OK here.
But another component `mainGrid` needs to be given an array of `TrackCell` types:

```
<script setup lang="ts">

  import type { TrackCell } from '../../env.d';
  interface Props {
    grid: TrackCell[][];
  }
  const props = defineProps<Props>()

  console.log('mainGrid script setup');
  console.log(props.grid[0][0]);
    
</script>
```

The component is called from its parent like this:

```
 <mainGrid :grid = trackGrid>
 </mainGrid>
```

In this case I get an error that props.grid[0] is undefined.

As a check to ensure that the `trackGrid` array (and its constituent `trackCell`s) was defined and populated correctly, I temporarly moved the template for the `mainGrid` component into its parent, and everything then works as expected. So it appears that it's just the `defineProps' section which is incorrect.

`trackGrid` is reactive:

```
export const trackGrid: TrackCell[][] = reactive([] );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's a typescript error, most likely the problem occurs in the log statement:

```
console.log(props.grid[0][0]);
```

Probably `grid` is an empty array after initialization?

Try

```
console.log(props.grid[0]?.[0]);
```

or remove the statement altogether

---

As a quick fix, you could initialize `trackGrid` with an empty row:

```
export const trackGrid: TrackCell[][] = reactive([[]]);
```

Comment: I only added the log statement to show the problem more easily. Without it, the same `undefined` error occurs at the first use of one of the  cells in the template itself. Forget to say that TrackGrid is reactive.

Comment: Well there you go, that's the same error, just at a different position then. If you add the code where you build the `trackGrid` and the template where the error occurs, it should be easy to identify

Comment: This morning I find that your original answer was partly correct! Too long to explain in a comment, so I'll add an answer which shows the sequence of events.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there wasn't any problem with the component props as posted!
I added `console.log(props.grid[0][0]);` to solve a problem with the grid cells being undefined when they were used in the template.
But that was a silly thing to do because of course the component's `<setup>` is called before the data has been fetched (in `onBeforeMount`).

*After* adding that erroneous debug line, I had corrected the actual error: I changed the declation of the array from

```
export const trackGrid: TrackCell[][] = reactive([...Array(8)].map(_=>Array(8)) );
```

to

```
export const trackGrid: TrackCell[][] = reactive([] );
```

but then I didn't remove the erroneous debug log!

Still not sure through if it should be

```
export const trackGrid: TrackCell[][] = reactive([] );
```

or

```
export const trackGrid: TrackCell[][] = reactive([[]] );
```

as both seem to work.

Anyway I hope that my original question may help someone in the future deal with arrays using TS with Vue.